# Android Studio Reformat Code uses different rules

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When creating new predefined XML files (e.g. a layout file or an activity), Android Studio uses one format.

Then, after hitting Code>Reformat Code - one gets slightly different look of the file.

Is there any way to make Android Studio using the same format syntax when creating new files and running Reformat Code command (so one doesn't have to hit Ctrl+Alt+L each time to make sure all files looks the same)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that you're trying to maintain the same format syntax that uses Eclipse. This guide could help you: [How to Add 'Eclipse Code Formatter' to Android Studio](https://github.com/blstream/MyGuide/wiki/%28Android%29-How-to-Add-Eclipse-Code-Formatter-to-Android-Studio).

Comment: The `Eclipse Code Formatter` option no longer seems to exist there under *File >> Settings >> Plugins >> Install JetBrains plugin...*. Rather, I had to go into *... >> Plugins >> Browse repositories...* instead. Done using Android Studio 2.3.3; haven't tested whether it works properly or not yet.